# What is relationship between App_Licenses.dll and licx?

Tags: asp.net, licenses.licx

I am trying to understand how the licensing works in ASP.NET.
There is licx file, App_Licenses.dll file. And then there is a difference between how the licensing works for a WebSite and a WebApp project.

Any insight into these would be of great help.
Links, explanation are most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of any differences between WebSite and WebApp, but with a licx file, it is compiled into the app_Licenses.dll file. If its not generating for you - you can right click on your licx file and regenerate the dll.

As per MS -

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499908/app-license-dll-can-not-be-generated-automatically-in-asp-net-website

In a web application project, manually copy the .lic file to /bin folder. In a Website, this is done automatically.

At this pointm refresh the designer or rerun the project and the licensed control should work as expected.

Note: App_LICENSES.dll isn't required in a WAP. In Websites, App_LICENSES.dll is generated to contain the LICX as an embedded resource. In WAP, there is a project assembly which contains the embedded LICX resource, so a separate DLL is not necessary